# How to delete all occurances of an item from a dictionary of dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionary. The keys are the nodes in a graph. For example, let us suppose node i in the graph is represented by a key i in the dictionary. The value corresponding to this key is again a dictionary where the keys are the neighbors of node i in the graph. These keys have default value 1. Let us consider the following example-

The nodes in the graph are - [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Neighbors:

```
1->[2,4,5,6]

2->[3]

3->[4,6]

4->[1,6]

5->[1]

6->[1,3,4]
```

So the dictionary of dictionary looks like this:

```
{1:{2:1,4:1,5:1,6:1},2:{3:1},3:{4:1,6:1},4:{1:1,6:1},5:{1:1},6:{1:1,3:1,4:1}}
```

Now, at different stages of the algorithm that I am trying to implement, I need to delete all occurrences of a node x from the neighbor list of other nodes. If x=4, then after deletion, the dictionary of dictionary should look like this:

```
{1:{2:1,5:1,6:1},2:{3:1},3:{6:1},4:{1:1,6:1},5:{1:5},6:{1:1,3:1}}
```

I used a dictionary of dictionary instead of a dictionary of lists so as to make deletion efficient. But it still is expensive.

What is the most efficient of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the structure you have chosen is not the most efficient possible. Sets might just fit the bill.

I did not quite understand if your connections are arrow-like one-way connections or two-way connections. I assume one-way connections, as 2 is neighbour of 1, but not vice versa. If this is the case, we need to keep track of "from" and "to".

I have modified your code to use sets instead of dictionaries for efficiency.

```
pointing_to = {
    1: set([2,4,5,6]),
    2: set([3]),
    3: set([4,6]),
    4: set([1,6]),
    5: set([1]),
    6: set([1,3,4]) }

pointed_by = {
    1: set([4,5,6]),
    2: set([1]),
    3: set([2,6]),
    4: set([1,3,6]),
    5: set([1]),
    6: set([1,3,4]) }
```

(Of course, the `pointed_by` can be created with a short piece of code, I just wrote it out to show the idea.)

Now, if you need to remove all connections to and from node `tbr`:

```
# remove tbr from pointing_to lists of all neighbours pointing to tbr
# (connections from other nodes to tbr
for n in pointed_by[tbr]:
    pointing_to[n].remove(tbr)
# after this tar is pointed by no neighbour
pointed_by[tbr] = set()

# repeat for opposite direction (connections from tbr to other nodes)
for n in pointing_to[tbr]:
    pointed_by[n].remove(tbr)
pointing_to[tbr] = set()
```

This should be relatively fast and simple to understand.

If there were only bidirectional connections, one dictionary and half of the above code would suffice.

---

A few words on the performance.

As can be seen, this approach has a very short loop. It iterates only through the connections with one end at the node to be deleted. At that level the total number of connections does not matter, nor the total number of points.

However, deeper down the set and dictionary lookup times are not independent of the size of these dictionaries and sets. My guess is O(log n), where n is the total number of points or connections, but someone may know the actual implementation better.

The use of sets is slightly faster than the use of dictionaries, but the difference is slight, as they are almost the same thing below the hood. Simple set operations tend to be quite fast.

My guess is that linear search methods are faster with very small datasets, as they may use list comprehensions &c. With larger data this will be more efficient.

Comment: I did keep a neighbors_of data structure once, but did not think of using sets though! Thanks. I had decided to change the approach because I thought there would be too much to do in pre-processing stage to create the nieghbors-of data structure and that might be costly if the graph is huge in size.

Comment: I am afraid you have a trade-off between memory and number of CPU cycles. If you want to spare memory, you only store the connections once. If you want to make it fast, you store them twice. Creating the reverse table is after all a fast operation with very few lines of code. (I guess that if you have tens of millions of connections, you cannot live with O(n) algorithms later on, because they tend to become O(n^2) when you take all processing into account.)

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{ok: {ik: iv for ik, iv in ov.iteritems() if ik != x} 
 for ok, ov in yourdict.iteritems()}
```

This rebuilds your dictionary with one that omits all keys matching `x` from the inner dictionaries.

Replace `iteritems()` for `items()` in Python 3.

Demo:

```
>>> yourdict = {1:{2:1,4:1,5:1,6:1},2:{3:1},3:{4:1,6:1},4:{1:1,6:1},5:{1:5},6:{1:1,3:1,4:1}}
>>> x = 4
>>> {ok: {ik: iv for ik, iv in ov.iteritems() if ik != x} 
...  for ok, ov in yourdict.iteritems()}
{1: {2: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1}, 2: {3: 1}, 3: {6: 1}, 4: {1: 1, 6: 1}, 5: {1: 5}, 6: {1: 1, 3: 1}}
```

Comment: Martijn Pieters I love you. Very neat

Comment: Thank you. Took me some time to understand it. Can you please explain what the complexity will be?

Comment: O(n), where n is the total number of connections, as it walks through both the inner and the outer dictionaries. Whether or not this is a problem depends heavily on n. What is your n?

Comment: @SatarupaGuha: It is a straight loop through all outer and inner keys. You have, at most, 2 times the number of nodes listed in that at the start.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in-place. You could use `copy.deepcopy` first to get it as a copy.

```
t = {1:{2:1,4:1,5:1,6:1},
     2:{3:1},
     3:{4:1,6:1},
     4:{1:1,6:1},
     5:{1:5},
     6:{1:1,3:1,4:1}}

for k,v in t.iteritems(): 
    v.pop(4, None)     

print t 
{1: {2: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1},
 2: {3: 1},
 3: {6: 1},
 4: {1: 1, 6: 1},
 5: {1: 5},
 6: {1: 1, 3: 1}}
```

You could encapsulate it as a helper function:

```
def remove_node(graph, node, inplace=True):
    import copy
    temp_graph = copy.deepcopy(graph) if not inplace else graph
    for k,v in temp_graph.iteritems():
        v.pop(node, None)
    return temp_graph
```